Some Devices Not Connecting through switch ethernet
So I have a managed switch(mokerlink 10g 12 port sfp) and router(cisco 4331) I have been working with.
Standard computers connected through the switch can get an ip through dhcp and connect to the internet no issues using fiber or ethernet. Meanwhile, other devices wont connect using the same configurations.
The 2 devices not working currently are a Amazon Fire Stick, and the one I'm Focusing on is a Cudy AC1200 wifi access point. The access point is sending dhcp messages sucesfully as checked using wireshark which was placed on the wan interface of the ap, but seems to not reach anything for some reason. When connecting the Cudy access point or fire stick directly to the router it gets connectivity just fine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

At what point did you "listen in" with wireshack to observe the DHCP requests? At the router, the switch or between device and switch? Please edit your question (there is an edit link just below the question) to provide that crucial additional information. While you are editing: You'll have a mark-down editor at your disposal. Insert some line-breaks please to make it a bit less "a wall of text"

I partially stated I listened to the ap over wireshark. but i updated my question to make it more apparent.

Does the switch at least report the link being up and at the expected speed? Does it have port counters that would show it's receiving something from the AC1200?

The link refuses to go up on the switch with the ac1200. The same port works on standard computers, but not other devices like the AC1200 and a fire stick.

most of my 10 gig gear dropped support for 10mbps ethernet and fast ethernet (I forget which).  I wonder if the SFP switch or modules don't have support some slower speed its dropping down to

@JourneymanGeek After a some research on the device speeds, The AC1200 and fire stick uses 10 or 100mbps, while the switch supports a minimum of 100mbps. You were correct, the sfp module seems to only support 1000Base-T. Which is why computers with auto-negotiate and higher speeds work fine, while the AC1200 and fire stick can only accept slower speeds. I will get a new module and see if the issue persists.
I cant believe this issue was so simple, I just overlooked it thinking it was a more complicated solution using  the switch or router configurations lol. Thankyou for your help!

I'll post an answer - I actually faced this during testing some gear but I wasn't sure if that was 'the' answer

In my experience - 10 gig sfp modules and many 'native' devices don't drop down to 10mbps ethernet or 100 mbps speeds. Quite a few lower end machines only use/need these speeds. You could run gigabit SFP modules on SFP+ - and that'll drop down to those speeds. Alternatively run a separate gigabit switch (or possibly a 2.5 gig switch, I believe they'll do the slower speeds and there's models with 10g uplink) for legacy machines.
In my experience- quite a few lower end routers had fast ethernet + AC wireless, so another option might be to 'simply' upgrade the wireless router. Modern wifi6 devices are all gigabit across the board.
